# Scroll bar appears on IE whereas it should not

Tags: html, css

I have a left menu with this CSS class :

```
.menu {
    overflow-y: auto;
    width: 210px;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #7145A1;
}
```

On Firefox and Chrome, the scroll bar appears only when a resize the window. On IE, a scroll bar appears directly when the page is loaded..

Did i forget something ?

Comment: Firefox, IE and Chrome do not manage width in the same way, regarding to margin and padding. Maybe your block is actually larger in IE than with the other browers. But we need your HTML code to analyse your problem further.

Comment: In that vein, your content may be taller in IE than in other browsers, just tall enough to trigger a scrollbar (which also changes the width of the viewport, possibly making the content even taller).

Answer (score 0):

No you didn't. Internet Explorer just processes the css differently than Firefox or Chrome and the result is that it shows the scrollbar always.

The solution would be to create a IE css tag that prevents that from happening!

```
<!--[if IE]>
// IE related css. 
<!--[endif]>
```

Right now idk how to fix it myself but you might find an anwser. Keep in mind, if you use the tag overflow:auto in IE that means it will always be visible in IE. Maybe you can create a script that regulates the scrollbar, whenever you are resizing that the script add's the overflow tag and removes it when the window reached a certain size. It's not a "beautiful" solution, but it might work ;)

Comment: OMG, IE... Ok, so i will try to declare a specifics rules for IE in a seperate file ..

Answer (score 0):

Does the scroll bar move a bit?
In this case, it is maybe because when you specify `height:100%`, IE sets the **content** height and adds a little margin (what is the .menu element? a div? a nav? )
So in this case you may just add `box-sizing:border-box`  to your class (be careful to cross-browser compatibiliy! http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp ... What is the version of I.E you use?).

If the scroll bars are "locked" (you can not scroll, they are just displayed), well, it is strange, normally the `overflow:auto` displays it just if it is necessary... But I.E does strange things sometimes.

An other point: prior to I.E 8, the `overflow` property **isn't supported**, and for I.E 8, you should use the `-ms-overflow` property. So in this special case, I don't know the default value (it should be `visible`, so without scroll bars, but for I.E I don't know...)

I hope I helped,