# Flex header/content/footer causes unneeded scrollbar in IE but not other browsers

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Hello I have this single .html file. When I open it in Chrome/Firefox/etc it works as expected, but when I open it with IE there is a unneeded vertical scrollbar that has very little "play". What is causing this and how can I fix it? Is there a better way to set headers/content/footers with css?

Thanks here's a screencap.

[image: Screenshot of file in IE]

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.box .row {
  border: 1px dotted grey;
}

.box .row.header {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  /* The above is shorthand for:
  flex-grow: 0,
  flex-shrink: 1,
  flex-basis: auto
  */
}

.box .row.content {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.box .row.footer {
  flex: 0 1 40px;
}
</style>

<div class="box">
    <div class="row header">
        <p><b>header</b>
        <br />
        <br />(sized to content)</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row content">
        <p>
        <b>content</b>
        (fills remaining space)
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="row footer">
        <p><b>footer</b> (fixed height)</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this.

**Method 1**: The simplest way would be to hide the scrollbars under a `<style>` tag as shown:

```html
body {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Likewise, `overflow-x: hidden` will hide the horizontal scrollbar, and `overflow: hidden` will hide both horizontal and vertical scrollbars. **Beware, however, that this not only hides the scrollbars, but removes its functionality.** Therefore, if you add more content that exceeds the display of your page, it will just be cut off.

---

**Method 2**: If you want to hide the scrollbar but **keep its functionality**, then replace the above code with:

```html
<style>
  body::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: none;  
  }
</style>
```

This should occur across all browsers, in case your issue persists elsewhere.

---

**Method 3**: If you want this to specifically happen **only for Internet Explorer**, try the following:

```html
<style>
  .container {
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
    overflow: auto;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: I tried the second solution but I'm getting the same behavior. I won't try the first solution as I will need the scroll functionality later if my content gets large enough.

Comment: Noted. I've added a third solution, I think that should do the trick!

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is not that I want to hide the scroll bar, I want to know why I am getting a scroll bar specifically in IE but not in Chrome or any other browser.

Comment: I think Internet Explorer processes CSS differently, which might be causing your problem. Unfortunately I don't use it often. Have you tried any of these solutions?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36302593/scroll-bar-appears-on-ie-whereas-it-should-not